# jquery un-hover

Tags: jquery

I have this script to cause a background color on a paragraph on hover of link within the paragraph. What I don't know how to do is cause it to return to the original background color once I "un-hover".

```
$(function(){
    $(".box a").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fff200');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider using `:hover` pseudo selector and doing this in CSS without any JavaScript.  See http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/hover.html

Comment: I don't think I can use only CSS because I'm changing the color of a parent item. I don't think you can select a parent selector in CSS alone.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The function below works as `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

```
$(function () {
    $(".box a").hover(function () {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fff200');
    }, function () {
        // change to any color that was previously used.
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fff200');
    });
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly (except the second background color had to be the original color - #fff in my case - not the hover color).

Comment: I know that's why I put the comment there to change to previous color :) glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

**JQuery**

```
$(".box a").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fff200');
 }, function() {
     $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#ffffff');
 });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/fTZfT/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a hover out handler in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1). That's where you'd want to return the color to the original.  If all you are doing is changing color, why not use CSS?

```
$(function(){
    $(".box a").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#fff200');
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#originalhexcolor');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think I can use only CSS because I'm changing the color of a parent item. I don't think you can select a parent selector in CSS alone.

Comment: I see..then I guess jQuery is the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use jQuery for this, use `addClass()` rather than `css()`:

```
$('.box a').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.box').addClass('hoveredOver');
}, function(){
    $(this).closest('.box').removeClass('hoveredOver');
});
```

With the CSS:

```
.hoveredOver {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BeYGn/4/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).