# Event triggering when not hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hiding a `div` when user hover over one of the menu element. I am using this code for this purpose

```
jQuery("#menu-item-15").hover(function(){
jQuery(".bootom-menu").css("display", "none");
});
```

But i want to display `bootom-menu div` when user will not be hovering (un-hover) over this specific menu element.

Comment: So give it the second method.  `hover()` takes two methods, the first being the hover start, and the second the hover end

Comment: Have you heard about CSS's `:hover`?

Comment: Ref. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: `bootom` what is **bootom**? You mean *bottom*?

Comment: bootom-menu class is not inside main menu. So that is why i was trying to do this via jquery.  I did not develop this menu and just making this update. 

This is a separate div (section).

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me finally. Here is the reference link from where i get idea about this. [jquery un-hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275956/jquery-un-hover)

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#menu-item-15").hover(function(){
jQuery(".bootom-menu").css("display", "none");
}, function(){
 // change back
jQuery(".bootom-menu").css("display", "block");
});
});
```

This code is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hover function accepts functions to handle in/out events.

Example:

```
$('#element').hover(
    function(){ 
        /* hover handle */ 
    }, function(){
        /* un-hover handle */ 
    }
);
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Done. Thanks for your feedbacks

Comment: FYI *"hover"* and *"un-hover"* are technically called `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. And those exact events are used in the `.hover(meFn, mlFn)` method.

Comment: I know it. This is described in the documentation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS if you're targeting a child or next-sibling element

```
#menu-item-15:hover .bootom-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: bootom-menu class is not inside main menu. So that is why i was trying to do this via jquery.  I did not develop this menu and just making this update.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **toggle**:

html

```
<div id='menu_element'>MENU ELEMENT</div><br><br><br><div id='bottom_menu'>BOTTOM MENU DIV</div>
```

css

```
#menu_element, #bottom_menu {
  background: steelblue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#menu_element").hover(function(){
$("#bottom_menu").toggle();
});
```

**Result**:

[image]